# Parallel computing: cores vs threads

Tags: parallelization, kernel-startup

I'm running Mathematica on a machine wtih 48 cores and 96 threads. I want to limit the number of threads the computation can have access to. If I give LaunchKernels[1] it correctly launches a single kernel, but then the computation is distributed over many more threads (48, which I guess is some default value or the max license number). Is there a way to limit the number of threads?

Thanks,
Paolo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems I misunderstood the kind of threading you were addressing when writing my original reply (below).  For internally multithreaded functions launched from a single kernel I you can limit the cores used with this setting:

```
(* e.g. two cores *)

SetSystemOptions[
 "ParallelOptions" -> {"MKLThreadNumber" -> 2, "ParallelThreadNumber" -> 2}]
```

---

Have you already explored the **Parallel** menu under **Edit** >  **Preferences**?  Specifically the **Manual setting** under **Local Kernels** would appear to be what you seek.

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ParallelTools/tutorial/ConfiguringAndMonitoring.html

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The machine is a server without graphic interface (do you know the corresponding config file?) However: 1) if I understand correctly this solution is not ideal: if I set (say) Manual = 4 wouldn't this apply to *all* computations? I would like the freedom to set the number of Kernels differently each time. 2) the problem does not seem to be the number of Kernels. I can launch a single one using LaunchKernels[1] inside the notebook, but then the computation uses many more threads anyway. It's like the single core distributes the computation over many threads, using all resources.

Comment: Addendum: apparently the license number of kernels is 16 (as per $ConfiguredKernels). However, even when using a single kernels it launches many more threads than 16

Comment: @Paolo I see now.  I think you need to set the `"ParallelThreadNumber"` and `"MKLThreadNumber"` in `SystemOptions["ParallelOptions"]` to limit that kind of multi-threading, but I don't think you can specify that per computation other than to change the setting and then change it back.  I shall admit I haven't tried to do this myself as I only have four cores to work with.

Comment: thank you so much. You are right: indeed, current settings are MKLThreadNumber -> 48, ParallelThreadNumber -> 48